# WindowManager-Bad token exception only on Android 6

Tags: java, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a class that extends Service.

```
public class CustomService extends Service {
  private ImageView chatHead;
  private WindowManager.LayoutParams params ;
  private ImageView iv;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    iv = new ImageView(this);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), ...);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    //INITIALIZE FROM SCREEN DIMENSIONS
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    //PARAMETERS
    params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    params.x = 0;
    params.y = mHeight - chatHeadRadius ;

    windowManager.addView(iv, params); // HERE WE HAVE THE CRASH
  }
}
```

I create the service from my mainActivity this way :

```
        startService(new Intent(getApplication(), MyService.class));
```

This code works really good on devices with Android 4 and 5. But when I try to run it on Marshmallow , I get the crash.

I have to inform you that I have already tried to put the permission

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
> ```

in my Manifest file but it did not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for that problem (with the help of a colleague :)

So , all the job is done before start the service in my MainActivity. 
I had to check if the user had enabled the [Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION).
If the user does not have that permission enabled, I start a Settings activity in order to enable that permission the user himself.

```
public void checkDrawPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
        } else {
            // display over lay from service
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
        }
    }else
    {
        // display over lay from service
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                // You have permission
                // display over lay from service
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```